# Why does std::make_tuple turn std::reference_wrapper<X> arguments into X&?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, reference-wrapper

In the C++11 standard it states that (see [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple), see also section 20.4.2.4 of the standard) it states that

```
template< class... Types >
tuple<VTypes...> make_tuple( Types&&... args );
```

> Creates a tuple object, deducing the target type from the types of arguments.
>
> For each `Ti` in `Types...`, the corresponding type `Vi` in `Vtypes...` is `std::decay<Ti>::type` unless application of `std::decay` results in `std::reference_wrapper<X>` for some type `X`, in which case the deduced type is `X&`.

I am wondering: Why are reference wrappers treated special here?

Comment: I think the main point is `std::reference_wrapper` is a conventional marker (treated specially) that was necessary before rvalue references, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080493/semantics-for-wrapped-objects-reference-value-by-default-via-stdmove-stdref?rq=1 . I think it should be necessary anymore in C++11 but the convention persisted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is more or less the primary purpose of `reference_wrapper`.

Normally, `std::make_tuple` always makes tuples of *values* (`std::decay` simulates pass-by-value semantics). Given `int x, y; std::make_tuple(x, y);` makes a `std::tuple<int, int>`, even though it will have deduced `Types` as a pack of references `int&, int&`. `std::decay` converts those to `int, int`.

`reference_wrapper` allows you to force creation of tuples of *references*: `std::make_tuple(std::ref(x), y)` will make a `std::tuple<int&, int>`.

Other parts of the standard library use `reference_wrapper` in the same way. As an example, `std::bind` will usually copy/move the bound arguments into the resulting object, but if you want it to store only a reference, you can explicitly request it by passing a `reference_wrapper`.

Comment: Note that this makes it impossible to `make_tuple` and generate a `tuple` containing a `std::reference_wrapper<int>`, but you can `make_tuple` and generate a `tuple` containing `std::reference_wrapper<int>&`.  I find this amusing.

Comment: Yeah, but there's little advantage of a tuple of reference_wrappers over a tuple of references.

Answer (score 4):

Your title is misleading: using `std::reference_wrapper<X>` turns the members to be `X&` rather than `X`. The reason this transformation is done is that `std::reference_wrapper<T>` is an auxiliary type, meant to turn a value type into a reference type. However, the extra conversion needed to make it appear that way sometimes interferes with the usage. Thus, unwrapping the reference where possible seems a reasonable approach: making the `std::tuple<...>` member a `T&` makes the use more natural.

Answer (score 0):

People are usually using `std::reference_wrapper<X>` to hold non-copyable types. Therefore, copying them in `make_tuple` would beat the purpose (and may break the build if the copy constructor is deleted). That is the reason why it uses reference (instead of a value) in it's return type.